# Restringir acceso a un archivo cron (Trabajo automático)

Tags: php, cron

He creado un **Cron job** con cPanel (Trabajos automáticos) y para ello he escrito un código en un archivo php que es ejecutado cada día automáticamente. Este archivo, cada vez que es ejecutado, reinicia el conteo de visitas y es por eso que quiero hacer algo para **evitar que se ejecute de forma directa**, pero no se me ocurre nada.

Comment: Ingresa tu solución como respuesta y luego marcala como respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución y he pensado en compartirla:

Si colocamos los archivos del cron dentro de la carpeta `public_html`, estos serán accesibles desde el dominio principal, ya que esta carpeta generada por defecto, está asignada para ello.

Debemos colocar los archivos de nuestro cron en una carpeta, y sacarla fuera del directorio public_html, de esta forma:

[image]